How does one serve and html5 (or webasm) app AND a websocket server on the same IP and port with nginx
I am working on a "client" webapp/page that we currently access via a local nginx via http://localhost:8080 The app runs a webasm websocket client. ( rust compiled to webasm )
The simple test websocket server runs in a separate process that listens to a hard coded Ip address and port ( 127.0.0.1:8081 } and runs on the same machine as the nginx server for the page.   The config for the nginx test web page (client app) is:
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /opt/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}

Howtos on setting up a "proxy" for a websocket server from an nginx front end say "add this" (the below) to the nginx config file:
http {
    server {
        listen 3000;
        server_mame ws.serverlab.ca

        location / {
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;

           proxy_pass http://ws-backend;

           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
    }

    upstream ws-backend {
        # enable sticky session based on IP
        ip_hash;

        server server01:3000;
        server server02:3000;
        server server03:3000;
    }
}     

In the howto config, is server for port 3000 separate from the one for port 8081 in our original nginx config and ADDED to it, or is it a replacement for the one for port 8080 ?  with a test port for both as 3000 ?
How do I direct the client connections from the page served to http://localhost:8080 to connect to our test websocket server running on 127.0.0.1:8081 ?
Is there some magic for the port 3000 ?  Or just a placeholder for the internal websocket server's listen port ? etc.
I'm a bit fuzzy on what to do here.  Should I be looking at the "reverse proxy" setup ?
Thanks.
